# How do I free a pointer without break the list?

Tags: c, linked-list

so, I just coded a Insertion Sort to sort a linked list (wiith dummy cell).

It works pretty good, but, at the end of the code, If I use free() in a pointer that I used as auxiliar, It's free also one of my cell (the last one it pointer in the loop).

So in order to avoid it free my cell, first I'm pointing de pointer to NULL, but here's my question: Wasn't it supposed to free just the pointer and not my cell if I didn't pointed NULL?

Here's my function

```
void 
insertSort(cel *lst){
    cel *temp = NULL;
    cel *ordenado = lst->prox;

    while(ordenado){
        cel *valorOrdenando = ordenado->prox;

        // removendo o valorOrdenado da lista
        ordenado->prox = valorOrdenando->prox;

        for (cel* i = lst; i != ordenado->prox; i = i->prox)
        {
            if (valorOrdenando->valor <= (i->prox)->valor || i->prox == ordenado->prox){
                temp = i->prox;
                i->prox = valorOrdenando;
                valorOrdenando->prox = temp;

                break;
            }
        }
        ordenado = ordenado->prox;

    }
    // and here is where I point to NULL, otherwise I lost a cell
    temp = NULL;
    free(temp);
}
```

Here's the other part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



struct cel {
    int valor;
    struct cel *prox;
}typedef cel;


void inserir (cel **lista, int x) {
    cel *temp = NULL, *aux = *lista;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(cel));
    temp->valor = x;
    temp->prox = NULL;


    if (*lista == NULL)
      *lista = temp;
    else {
      for (; aux->prox != NULL; aux = aux->prox);
      aux->prox = temp;
    }
 }

 void imprimir(cel *lista) {
    for (cel *aux = lista; aux != NULL; aux = aux->prox)
        printf("%d ,", aux->valor);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    cel *list = NULL;

    inserir(&list, 3);
    inserir(&list, 2);
    inserir(&list, 1);
    inserir(&list, 8);
    inserir(&list, 6);
        insertSort(list);
        //bubbleSort(list->prox);
    imprimir(list->prox);
    return 0;
}
```

How should I code so that I didn't need to user `*temp = NULL` and why Is it happening currently??

Comment: As an advice: always use English words to name identifiers.

Comment: These statements     temp = NULL;
    free(temp); do not make sense.:)

Comment: You don't `free` pointers. You `free` the memory blocks they point to. So don't ask yourself 'am I finished with this pointer?', rather ask yourself 'am I finished with the memory block it's pointing to?'. A pointer itself is just a variable like any other - you don't need to `free` an `int` once you're finished with it ...

Comment: Another, related way to look at it is that you pair `free()` calls with corresponding `malloc()` calls, not with pointer declarations.  The `malloc` and its corresponding `free` do not have to be in the same function, but in your particular function, it is unlikely to be appropriate to `free` any memory.

Comment: @Mateusmsouza And it seems the function insertSort does not change the head of the list after exiting. I think the function should be declared like void 
insertSort( cel **lst ); or it is better to use the following name of the function void insertionSort( cel **list );

Comment: @Mateusmsouza As you didn't allocate memory in the function using malloc then there is nothing to free.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception about how pointers work in C. When you declare a pointer, it is just like declaring any other variable. 
If you declare a pointer locally (inside a function, without a modifier such as static) the memory position it occupies will be handled by lower layers that the language C abstracts for you. One common implementation is to use a stack, when you declare a variable locally it will be pushed onto the stack when the function is called and will be popped out of the stack once the function returns, so there is no need to worry about deallocating your pointers.

However, a pointer points to a certain memory position and when you use a function like malloc it allocates a free memory block for you and the pointer points to the first position of the block. Now that block will only return to the free block list when you free it. So once you have finished using that memory location you should free it.

When you did:

```
temp = NULL;
free(temp);
```

You were trying to free the NULL memory position, which does not make sense.
So you are only going to free a memory once you do not need it anymore.

I suggest you search more about variables and pointers in the C language, this link might help you:
[enter link description here](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)

Comment: You've got a misconception about `const` - a `const` does not affect whether or not the variable will be put on stack, and neither does leaving it out mean that it would be put on stack, and there might not even be a thing called stack in the implementation. A `const int` in C is an object to be placed in memory just as much as an `int` would be.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : I had a misconception about `const`. Thank you for the clarification. You also said that there might not even be a stack in the implementation, what I understood from this is that I cannot assume that a stack will be used to implement a C program in assembly. I will edit my answer, could you check if the edited answer is correct ?

Comment: C does not require that the program be implemented in assembly either. One can for example interpret C code in Python. The code need not be in the memory addressable as data, and so on... But most proper C compilers that compile to assembly would use a stack in some way or other, yes.